# os.makedirs() / os.mkdir() on Windows. No error, but no (visible) folder created

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just try to create some new folders with Python's (3.7.3) os.makedirs() and os mkdir().
Apparently, it works fine because no error occurs (Win 10 Home). But as I try to find the created folder in the windows explorer it isn't there.

Trying to create it again with python I get an error: 
'[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:'

Strange thing is, all this worked fine on my computer at work (Wind 10 too), and also on my android tablet.

I've already tried to use relative & absolute paths in makedirs / mkdir.

## Ok, it's all about these few lines:

```
import os

# print(os.getcwd()) shows: C:\Users\Andrej\Desktop

# tried relative path..
os.makedirs('Level1/Level2/Level3')

# tried out some absolute paths like...
os.makedirs('C:/Users/Andrej/Desktop/Level1/Level2/Level3') 
os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\Andrej\\Desktop\\Level1\\Level2\\Level3')
```

UPDATE: It works perfectly when I write makedirs command directly in the Windows powershell. The issue above only occurs when I write this code in Visual Code Studio and then start the file from the powershell by typing in: python makedirs.py...

Comment: Sounds like it has created the directories, but either it's created them somewhere other than where you expect, or there's some authorisation issue meaning you can't see them

Comment: For the last one, the : is in the wrong place:
os.makedirs('C\\:Users\\Andrej\\Desktop\\Level1\\Level2\\Level3')
Should be:
os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\Andrej\\Desktop\\Level1\\Level2\\Level3')

Comment: Yes, since it is my own pc where I have admin rights, I enabled the option to see hidden folders and files...However, nothing appears..I also looked up in the python installation folder...just in case it has some issues with the relative path..nothing. PS: Yea the : was wrong, sorry, I typed in the code manually, in my file it's set in the right place

Comment: I don't understand the difference between *when I write makedirs command directly in the Windows powershell* and *start the file from the powershell by typing in: python makedirs.py*. The code is correct, all 3 times, though the relative path probably doesn't create the folders where you expect. So please amend your question to show us exactly how you are running the code in each case. It has nothing to do with permissions (you don't need admin rights for your desktop folder), and even if it did, you would get an error message about that.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain: I tested two ways to run the code. ||| 1.WAY: Write a file named mdirs.py --> save it --> go to Windows PowerShell --> go to the dir of the file by typing in cd Desktop --> run the mdirs.py by typing in python mdirs.py ||| 2.WAY: Open PowerShell --> type in python to start python --> type in import os --> type in: os.makedirs('C:/Users/Andrej/Desktop/Lv1/Lv2'). ||| There's no problem at all when I go about the 2.WAY. I see the folders created as intended. I run into the described issue of 'invisible' folders only if I pick the 1.WAY to create them.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same thing happen to me, except I was creating a folder in the AppData/Roaming directory and was using the version of Python from the Microsoft Store.

Apparently, files and directories created in AppData using that version of Python, will instead be created in:

```
%LocalAppData%\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what causes this problem finally!

All of the created test folders have been moved to a folder named VTROOT. This folder is created by Comodo Internet Security I use...Its "Auto-Containment" moved all folders I set up by running the code from .py-file (only then) in the PowerShell.

Disabling the auto-containment of Comodo solves the problem..Oh my..

Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

the "`if`" part will check if the file exists already and consequentially solve the ERROR: '*[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:*'

the "`import sys`" part will fix the issue with windows where the folder is created but not visible by the user (even with show hidden files turned on)

```
import sys
import os

path = 'your path'
def make_dir():
    if not os.path.exists(Path):
        os.makedirs(Path)
```

or

```
import sys
import os

path = 'your path'
def make_dir():
    mode = 0o666 #read and write for all users and groups 
    # form more permission codes search for: *chmod number codes*
    if not os.path.exists(Path):
        os.mkdir(Path, mode)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the below import statement:

```
import sys
```

This should work.

Comment: add more details to your answer

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this??? I was getting crazy with one situation and that worked!!! It was a network folder. PLEASE DONT UPVOTE!!!!