# os.mkdir succeeds but no directory appears in C:\Users\<user>

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Very simple script to demonstrate this oddity:

```
import os

root = input('Where to save?: ')

top = os.path.join(root, 'toplevel')
os.mkdir(top)

for i in range(10):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(top, str(i)))
```

When prompted, the `root` value is `C:\Users\joe1234`, and then it runs; however, only `C:\Users\joe1234\toplevel` appears and no subdirectories appear in the explorer.

To further the complication, when I run the script again with the same input, I get:

> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Users\joe1234\toplevel`

Hidden files are enabled and using `dir` with hidden attributes displays nothing. This issue does not occur when the input is just `C:\` or any other directory under `C:\<some_dir>`, only in the directories stemming under `C:\Users`.

I'm using CPython 3.6.0 and I am on Windows 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Comment: could it be a problem with permissions? since it is a user directory

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted If I am user `joe1234`, it shouldn't be; plus, the docs state `PermissionError` would be thrown. Additionally, if I run the `os.mkdir` from IDLE, the directories get created. The issue seems to occur only when running the interpreter via the command line and specifying the script.

Comment: this means folders already created successfully, the problem with file explorer that doesn't show the updated filesystem, to double check, you can open cmd line window and use dir command to show the contents of your target folder

Comment: @pstatix hey man, you shouldn't respond this way, i am here to help you.

Comment: @MahmoudElshahat I asked you a question, one that was to clarify whether or not you read the post before make a suggestion that was already covered in the post. I put in the post as reference for what I've tried to resolve the problem, it was to avoid having questions asked like the one you've commented.

Comment: @pstatix IDLE might have higher permissions, but you are correct that it should throw PermissionError, but in my experience that doesn't always occur - I don't have an explanation for that

Comment: maybe you can "play" with the `mode` argument of `mkdir` ?

Comment: Coul you try checking if the directory has been created using os.isdir to check if it exists in the program. This sounds like the file manager not updating immediately to me. It's possible the refresh for non user directories is quicket

Comment: For reference woks on linux so i doubt its the python code itself unless theres a bug in python

Comment: Not sure but I remember that Python asks for privilege access when you download it - I accepted all and this code works for me.

Comment: Maybe reinstalling Python to change this setting? Or you could change [**app permissions**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/app-permissions-aea98a7c-b61a-1930-6ed0-47f0ed2ee15c#:~:text=In%20Windows%2010%2C%20use%20the,permissions%20are%20on%20or%20off.).

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same version of Python when using IDLE? Check the _Image path name_ in Task Manger.

Comment: "To further the complication, when I run the script again with the same input, I get: FileExistsError"

That is expected of `os.mkdir`. Use `pathlib.Path.mkdir` to create nested directories, even if it already exists. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir

Comment: Can you navigate into `toplevel` folder? With `cd` or putting path in explorer?

Comment: Is it in the relative path of the command line where you run it from? Probably not, but just a speculation.

Comment: The error regarding toplevel already existing is completely expected since it already exists after the first run...

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to replicate the problem. I installed Python 3.6.6, and ran the script as you have it written, and I was able to successfully generate the folders in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into two *independent* problems.

### 1. `FileExistsError`

When you run your script second time with the same input, your script will  call `os.mkdir(top)`, where `top='C:\\Users\\joe1234\\toplevel'`, but this folder already exists (after first run). As stated in `os.mkdir` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir), it raises `FileExistsError`, when folder already exists.

So, if you will remove `toplevel` folder, then you will not get `FileExistsError`.

You can also change your script in two ways to not get this error:

```
# (a) check if folder already exists
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)

# (b) use try/catch
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

### 2. Not appearing subdirectories

This problem certainly lies in the environment rather than python itself. Unfortunately I can only guess, why subdirectories are not created.

Usually such weird problems related to antiviruses. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890985/2627487). There Comodo antivirus automatically putted "suspicious" python process into virtual (isolated) environment, like a sandbox, so folders were actually created in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated, but a much simpler idea would be to use `os.path.expanduser()` which will automatically find the user directory path (easier than your input function)

```
import os
dir_ = os.path.expanduser("~/toplevel")
os.mkdir(dir_)

for i in range(10):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(dir_, str(i)))
```

For your problem, you might be getting a `FileExistsError` because you may have forgotten to delete your `~/toplevel/` directory. The second time you run this, there will already be a toplevel directory, so if you want this to run successfully second time, you will need to delete that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use absolute paths (abspath) to make sure where you are sending your files.